# Custom Validator with .forEach - Can it be done differently (better)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I created my own validator class for practice. Is this a good approach or can it be done better?

```js
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class ProjectNameValidator {
   private static blackList = ['Test1'];
    static correctName(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null {
       const name: string = control.value;
       let isValid = true;
       ProjectNameValidator.blackList.forEach(forbiddenName => {
           if (forbiddenName === name) {
              isValid = !isValid;
           }
       });
       return isValid ? null : {'Forbidden name': true};
    }
}
```

Comment: The custom validator depends on how you handle the form and how you are going to manage the form when exception arisen. If you find this is good to your application, you go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `includes` as follows:

```
export class ProjectNameValidator {
  private static blackList = ['Test'];
  static correctName(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
    return ProjectNameValidator.blackList.includes(control.value) ?  { 'Forbidden name': true } : null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop over an entire list to check if one of them is invalid (forbidden), but as soon as you find one invalid you still continue checking and on top of that, if there's an even amount of forbidden names you match to you will end up allowing it. (isValid = !isValid).

I recommend using indexOf as follows:

```
ProjectNameValidator.blackList.indexOf(name) >= 0;
```

to quickly check if the entered value is contained within the blackList.

Answer (score 0):

How is my custom validator looks now:

```js
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export class ProjectNameValidator {
   private static blackList = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'];
    static correctName(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: boolean} | null {
       const name: string = control.value;
       const isInvalid =  ProjectNameValidator.blackList.indexOf(name) !== -1;
       return isInvalid ? {'Forbidden name': true} : null;
    }
}
```